# how to get Steam Inventory API or a way to get all steam items list ? how some sites have it?

Tags: c#, api, inventory, steam, steambot

i have been looking for a way to make a SteamBot,
to Trade my Steam Inventory Gifts for Keys or such.

the problem lies at the Steam Inventory ....
since as far as i learned , it don't have an official API yet ,
so i can't just do it like dota 2 and tf2 !

the closest thing i got was : 
using a link like this with the user's username in place of "unluckyped"

http://steamcommunity.com/id/unluckyped/inventory/json/753/1

but 2 big problem ! 
first , its not well detailed ,
2nd and the most important one , it only show me what i got ! not what the whole steam have !

so lets say after hours of coding , my bot can automatically get the name of the games i give to it , and i set the prices , and it work ,
but still it will only have a list of what i have , if it get offered something new it will not recognize .
except if ! i also make it so it will check the traders inventory too !

but isn't there an easier way to get all the list ?

how sites like tf2outpost  dota2outpost  dota2league  baazar.tf or dispencer.tf have something which can show u all items in steam inventory ?

Tnx a lot guys :D
hope i can find my answer :D

Edit :

I Don't know which part of my question is to board .

to sum it up , what i want is :

how to get Steam's inventory Full List of schema ? like when i use :

```
 http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_[AppID]/GetSchema/v0001/?key=[APIKey]
```

this url work for Dota 2 / TF2 or such games , but not for Steam inventory.

how do i get the steam inventory one ?

if there is no way , then how some site like i said before , have it ?

Tnx Again.

Comment: Why don't you get an [API Key](http://steamcommunity.com/dev)?

Comment: i did ! but that is not helping me , since the API key work to get me schema for Dota 2 or TF2 or CS GO or such , but not work for Steam inventory , the url example is :     api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_[appid]/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=[apikey]
it work for appid 570 ( dota2 ) or tf2 , but not work on 753 which is Steam

Comment: @Andy sorry copy pasted wrong url and can't edit now , it's api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_[AppID]/GetSchema/v0001/?key=[APIKey]

Comment: SteamBot already has support for this, using `GenericInventory`.  Also **I'm not sure why this was closed as too broad** - if anything, it's too specific, since it's about a specific site's API.  But since we have [many questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steam-web-api) about the same API with good answers, I see no reason to close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was checking my old questions and I noticed that this question got almost 2.5k views!
So I thought now that I've figured it out I should answer it myself so others can use it.

Well, if I remember correctly, all i wanted at that time was this url:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/
```

It doesn't even need an API Key. It gives you a list of ~16k AppIDs, that includes all steam inventory items.

This link and the link I gave in the question above works for getting a list of all items.

Just deserialize the JSON into a class that you can easily make for this JSON string, then you can do anything you want with the list of games or items.

I suggest adding [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to your resources too as it helps greatly.